# Word undo stack corruption (it behaves like a "redo stack"!)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, undo

Since a few days the undo stack (list of actions that can be redone) in *every* Word document behaves in a strange way. Just clicking the undo arrow is working correctly. Also the screen tip text which is shown when the mouse is pointing at the undo arrow shows the correct information. But when I try to open the list of actions that can be undone this list is *empty*. It only shows "cancel". After undo the first action this list shows the just *undone* action, after undo the second action this list shows *the last two undone* actions and so on! **Instead of becoming shorter and shorter with each undo step my list is elongated! The undo stack behaves like a "redo stack"!** Only after undoing the first change on the document the list is empty again. This is its first and only correct information!

Here I've uploaded a few pictures for illustration:
[Before first Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8GCK.png) 
[After first Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SewNf.png)
[After second Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLOtW.png)
[After third Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhMQp.png)
[After fourth Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zngrV.png)
[After last Undo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FqF7.png)

The only reason why Word has changed its behaviour I can imagine, is that I've done a lot VBA programming the last days. In my VBA macro I use the Application.UndoRecord function. While testing I often stopped it before it has called EndCustomRecord. But I think after closing the document and closing Word their shouldn't be any remnants of these unclosed CustomRecord objects. Also the erratic behaviour concerns *every* Word document: those which have *never* been in touch with my macro just as those which have been new created.

The following procedures didn't help: restart the computer, erase temp folder, delete Word informations upon unsaved files, deleting Normal.dotm, starting Word in safe mode, Office quick repair, Office extensive repair, sfc /scannow, Dism /RestoreHealth. Also there is no problem to open the same documents on another computer. There, the undo stack shows the expected information. **It's a Word application problem, not a problem of the documents.** At last I've tested Excel's undo stack on my computer: it works without any abnormalities.

Any ideas? Is there any central location where Word stores document undo informations? May I have produced something like an overflow by interupting my macro again and again and this overflow can't be reset by Word?

System: Windows 10 64-bit, Office Professional Plus 2016 32-bit

Comment: After going through the list you give my next thought would be to check whether there are any ADD-INS installed/running: File/Options/Add-ins as well as Developer tab/Add-ins (these would be templates loaded as add-ins).

Comment: Hallo Cindy, thanks a lot for answering. Your hint seems to point in the right direction, but didn't solve the problem. I've installed a citation program which includes a Word plug-in (Zotero). So I followed your idea and inactivated this plug-in. This done, the undo list suddenly worked fine! So I've reactivated the plug-in: still ok. But only until I've closed and re-opend Word again. So I've uninstalled Zotero, deleted all remnants of it in the file system and in the registry, done an Office online repair again: it doesn't help, the problem persists :-(